# Change Text formatting in TextField on Click of a button

Tags: flutter, dart

I want users to have an option to make text bold, italic, add underline and hyperlink on text in
the textfield with click of a button.

I have implemented this, I need an option to when user clicks on iconbutton (defined in the code), the text in the textfield should change.

PS - I have tried `zefyr` package but I need to implement these functions on my own stateful widget instead of zefyrScaffold.

I haven't tried making a function storing text formatting properties like `FontWeight.Bold` and then use it with conditions and bool because I'm quite positive that that's not the best solution.

After this I need text to maintain it's state because I'll be encoding the text in base64 format. So if I change text formatting, will it be same on other user's side after I encode it to base64?

```
TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    hintText: 'Start Typing your Message here',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 17,
                      color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle.color
                    )
                ),
                maxLines: null,
                minLines: 1,
                autocorrect: true,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                onChanged: (String str){
                  print(str);
                },
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title.color,
                fontSize: 19,
              ),
              ),
```

```
Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(LineIcons.times),
            iconSize: 27,
            onPressed: () {
              bottomChangeFunc();
            },
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(LineIcons.bold),
            iconSize: 27,
            color: Theme
                .of(context)
                .iconTheme
                .color,
            onPressed: () {
            },
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(LineIcons.italic),
            iconSize: 27,
            color: Theme
                .of(context)
                .iconTheme
                .color,
            onPressed: () {
            },
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(LineIcons.underline),
            iconSize: 27,
            color: Theme
                .of(context)
                .iconTheme
                .color,
            onPressed: () {
            },
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(LineIcons.link),
            iconSize: 27,
            color: Theme
                .of(context)
                .iconTheme
                .color,
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set this up with an enum and some style constants.

```dart
enum TextMode {
  normal,
  bold,
  italic,
  underline,
  // link,  <- I'm not sure what you want to have happen with this one
}

const normalStyle = TextStyle();
const boldStyle = TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
const italicStyle = TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic);
const underlineStyle = TextStyle(textDecoration: TextDecoration.underline);

// Helper method
TextStyle getStyle(TextMode mode) {
  switch(mode) {
    case TextMode.bold: return boldStyle();
    case TextMode.italic: return italicStyle();
    case TextMode.underline: return underlineStyle();
    default: return normalStyle();
  }
}
```

Then you can display the relevant style on your `TextField` based on the currently selected enum value:

```dart
TextField(
  ...,
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title.color,
    fontSize: 19,
  ).merge(getStyle(currentMode)),
),
```

To change the style, simply change the current `FontMode` in your button press handlers:

```dart
IconButton(
  ...
  icon: Icon(LineIcons.bold),
  onPressed: () => setState(() => currentMode = FontMode.bold),
),
// and so on for the other modes
```

Storing and retrieving the state is easy as enums are basically glorified integers.

Comment: What is currentMode supposed to be?

Comment: I've made a widget which returns row where all the buttons are present and I'm calling that instead of having all the buttons in the same Stateful Widget. How can I pass? For context ```Container( child: _textEditingBar(context, bottomChangeFunc)```. I'm doing this. So the TextField is in Stateful widget and _textEditingBar is a widget. So setState doesn't work in the widget as it's not stateful.